# How connect odoo (xmlrpc) with ionic running over ios?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, mobile, odoo, ionic3

I am working with ionic 3, I did an app to consume web services from odoo, for this I used a npm package: [odoo-xmlrpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo-xmlrpc).

it work fine with android, but when I simulate for iPhone, it can't connect with the server. I tried a manual connection, but it wasn't worked, it show an XHR error, but no show exactly the error.

I used a sniffer(charles) to show me http packages and I get some information. it try to connect using OPTIONS Method, but the server request is 404 not FOUND.

you can see all my code here: https://github.com/jose1914luis/rusia

my configurations:

ionic info:

```js
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.0 
    ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
    Node       : v9.3.0
    npm        : 5.6.0 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Ionic Code:

```js
import { Component, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import xmlrpc from 'xmlrpc';
import url from 'url';

import * as Odoo from 'odoo-xmlrpc'

enableProdMode();
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  msg = '';
  config = {url:'http://moscutourgratis.com', 
    port:'8069', 
    db:'Tour_Gratis_Rusia',
    username:'xxxx',
    password:'xxxx'};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {

   this.cargar();
  }

  cargar(){
   var self = this;
   var odoo = new Odoo(self.config);
   
    //Fail method with odoo-xmlrpc
   odoo.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
     self.msg += JSON.stringify(err);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
     return JSON.stringify(err);
    }
    self.msg += 'entro';
   });

    //manual connection Fail show XHR Error
    this.connect(function(err){
     self.msg += 'error interno' + JSON.stringify(err);
    });
  }
  

    connect(callback){
     
     var urlparts = url.parse(this.config.url);
     var host = urlparts.hostname;
     var port = this.config.port || urlparts.port;
     var db = this.config.db;
     var username = this.config.username;
     var password = this.config.password;
     var secure = true;
     if(urlparts.protocol !== 'https:') {
       secure = false
     }
     var uid = 0;
        var clientOptions = {
            host: host,
            port: port,
            path: '/xmlrpc/2/common'
        }
        var client;
        if(secure == false) {
          client = xmlrpc.createClient(clientOptions);
          console.log("client normal")
        }
        else {
          client = xmlrpc.createSecureClient(clientOptions);
          console.log(clientOptions)
          console.log("client sécurisé sur le port " + port)
        }
        var params = [];
        params.push(db);
        params.push(username);
        params.push(password);
        params.push({});
        client.methodCall('authenticate', params, function(error, value) {
            if(error){
                console.log('HOLA MUNDO ERROR DE MIERDA' + error);
              return callback(error, null)
            }
            uid = value;
            return callback(null)
        });
    }

}
```

Charles http packages:

[image]

Comment: The question title should be a brief description of the problem, not just a list of keywords.

Answer (score 1):

after spend 2 weeks solving this problem, I changed the library for [odoo-ionic-xml-rpc](https://github.com/jose1914luis/odoo-ionic-xml-rpc). Neither it didn't work. I found that the request return origin null in header additionally ionic >3 has integrate wkwebview, [this has some problems](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/):

- I can’t implement CORS. Unfortunately there’s no API to disable this, so you’ll need to ensure any remote API that your app use, implement CORS correctly: CORS MDN
- XHR requests do not work- I am trying to call some remote service using XHR (or fetch), but it is not working. As we said previously, WKWebView enforces CORS. You will need to whitelist http://localhost:8080 as “Origin” and/or implement CORS properly.

Basically you need to [Downgrade to UIWebView](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/#downgrading-to-uiwebview) and it worked.

modified confi.xml:

```
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />
```

uninstall cordova-plugin-ionic-webview:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save 
$ rm -rf platforms/
$ rm -rf plugins/
$ ionic cordova build ios
```